# Not able to get the `Content-Disposition` from backend response

Tags: javascript, angular, http, angular5

I am trying to get the value from `Content-Disposition` from my backend response. but I am not able to get that at all..

here is my code :

```
public getQuoteImage(sharedQuote):Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(environment.downloadSummarUrl, JSON.stringify(sharedQuote), { 
      headers: this.params.headers.validate,
      observe: "response",
      responseType : 'blob'
    });
  }
```

I am trying to get `filename` from `Content-Disposition` from the following:

```
downloadSummaryContent() {
    this.server.getQuoteImage(this.sharedQuote).subscribe((data) => {
      console.log( 'headers are', '\n', data, '\n',  data.headers.get('Content-Disposition') ); //but not getting the file name
      var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
      var a = document.createElement('a');
      document.body.appendChild(a);
      a.setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
      a.href = url;
      a.download = 'quote.pdf';
      a.click();
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
      a.remove(); // remove the element
    });
  }
```

[image]

But not getting the value at all.

in the console i am getting:

```
{
  "headers": {
    "normalizedNames": {

    },
    "lazyUpdate": null,
    "lazyInit": null,
    "headers": {

    }
  },
  "status": 200,
  "statusText": "OK",
  "url": "https:XXXXXXservice/p/shipment/download/",
  "ok": true,
  "type": 4,
  "body": {

  }
}
```

Comment: CORS requests only allows javascript to access the following response headers: `Cache-Control` `Content-Language` `Content-Type` `Expires` `Last-Modified` `Pragma` - unless the response includes `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` that give the javascript permission to access any others - see [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers)

Comment: note: did you write the server side? Because it is specifically allowing request headers that are actually response headers - a request will never send `Access-Control-Allow-*` headers, and it's also "allowing" `Access-Control-Request-*` headers. But these are under the control of the browser (never set in your code), and are set as required and never need to be explicitly allowed

Comment: @JaromandaX - it works after I added the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` - thank you!! I agree if you place your suggestion as answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN Access-Control-Expose-Headers documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers), CORS requests only allows javascript to access the following response headers:

- Cache-Control
- Content-Language
- Content-Type
- Expires
- Last-Modified
- Pragma

The server can allow access to other response headers using the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` response, so, for `Content-Disposition` to be accessible to the client, you would need to issue

```
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Disposition
```

header in the response